# Distance (km) significant but inverse not

Tags: regression

Could somone explain this to me please? I have a regression with one of my variables being the distance from one point to another. This value is measured in km. The closer the points are together the lower the value.

However, for interpreation I felt that the inverse of distance would make more sense. The closer you are to an area, holding all things equal....etc.

However, I'm getting two different results in my model whether I take distance or the inverse of distance 1/variable.

See output;

This is with normal distance the coeff. and level of significance.

sportmin |  -.0003924**

This is with the inverse of distance

inversesport |   .0265864

Could someone explain what the issue is?
Theorticually the variable should be significant positive or negative depending whether you use distance or the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 1/distance is not the inverse function for distance. 1/distance is an asymptotic function that is very curvy in its form, whereas distance is linear. Whenever you change the curvature of a variable, its statistical significance will change, e.g. log(variable) will behave very differently from variable in a regression model.

[image]

If you did a transformation that left the variable distance as a linear function, then it should not change its significance after having done the transformation.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for your informative reply! I suppose my next question what would you recommend?

Comment: I would say keep it as distance away from each other, without any transformation, and interpret accordingly. Your intercept is if they are in the same place as each other (which may or may not make any sense), and then each km apart the dependent variable increases by the coefficient specified. You should only be transforming if there are problems with your data... if it's not normally distributed or if it has heteroscedasticity in its residuals would be the top two that come to mind. It's generally better to keep the analyses simple if you can.